# VolleyError is the value I want

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm new using Vollay and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

I´m trying to get a json from an url and when I request it by "Vollay" It goes to the VolleyError and the error has the value I want.

Any idea why I'm getting it like an error? and how can I fix it?

Below you can see my code.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.getActivity());

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.getActivity(), "Wait please","Loading..");

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(Url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.e("My response", response.toString());
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("My response", error.toString());
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Url: [http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=666721920db27c5f3d996add6cdc048b&_render=json&destino=Sevilla+Prado+S.S.&id_destino=994&id_origen=999&origen=Sanlucar+d+Barrameda]http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=666721920db27c5f3d996add6cdc048b&_render=json&destino=Sevilla+Prado+S.S.&id_destino=994&id_origen=999&origen=Sanlucar+d+Barrameda

Error = com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value {"count":0,"value":{"title":"Get TimeTable Amarillos","description":"Pipes Output","link":"http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=666721920db27c5f3d996add6cdc048b","pubDate":"Mon, 06 Oct 2014 18:14:20 +0000","generator":"http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/","callback":"","items":[]}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Problem was I was trying to get a JsonArrayRequest and the result is a JsonObje

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("Response", response.toString());
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "headers: " + error.networkResponse.headers);
                    Log.e(TAG, "statusCode: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: i think the response header of your **response** has an error of 500. check with other stuff like RESTClient for mozilla.

Comment: I checked it again and the status is 200 OK. I'll try to figure out why it's happening that. I'm gonna try tonight a request to a different path and see if it works.

Comment: I have tried with a different path and I still getting the json inside the VollayError object.

Comment: Whats the type of error?

Comment: I have added the error I'm getting and looks like it can't cast it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets look at the response:

```
{

    "count": 0,
    "value": {
        "title": "Get TimeTable Amarillos",
        "description": "Pipes Output",
        "link": "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=666721920db27c5f3d996add6cdc048b",
        "pubDate": "Mon, 06 Oct 2014 18:22:13 +0000",
        "generator": "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/",
        "callback": "",
        "items": [ ]
    }

}
```

this is a `JSONObject` so you must not use `JsonArrayRequest`, change that to `JsonObjectRequest`.

Comment: ok, thanks let me try to implement it with Volley because I have never tried it.

Comment: just change `JsonArrayRequest` to `JsonObjectRequest` in your volley.